# Laravel Auth com Subdominio

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas, subdomínio, routing

Bom dia, estou tentando realizar um auth com subdominio, porém todas as vezes que logo no site retorna o erro de `Too Many Redirects`.

Esse é meu **.env**:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.meudominio.com.br
```

E a primeira linha de minha rota é essa:

```
Route::domain('sis.meudominio.com.br')->middleware('admin')->group(function (){
```

Eu estava tendo um problema em que todas as routes que não estavam nesse grupo funcionavam, então eu tive de colocar isso, na parte do website:

```
Route::domain('meudominio.com.br')->group(function(){ Auth::Routes();
```

O `Auth::Routes()` está lá, por que desejo que somente dê pra logar no caminho principal do site.

Comment: O Sistema está no subdomínio ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Rotas que pertencem a um subdominio deverão ser registradas dentro do grupo
// Rotas para subdominio devem sempre ser declaradas antes das outras
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.' . env('APP_DOMAIN')], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
});

// As demais rotas, registra-se normal
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Funcionou ! Obrigado.

Comment: Imagina! amigo!